# How to maintain balance and center of gravity when pushing a 100-ton piece of asteroid?

Tags: gravity, asteroid, mining, space-tug

I understand that rotating momentum around a fixed axis can help with the center of balance. But is it enough?

In my case, a space tug has to burn its engine for 1 min, accelerate a 100-ton piece of asteroid, and then disconnect from it. There will be no chance for trajectory corrections during orbit transfer from NEO asteroid to the Earth's atmospheric entry. Would this precise trajectory change be even possible when applied to the irregular shape of an asteroid rock?

Comment: the key words you should look into for this are "spin-stabilization."  I don't think the version of your question (can I spin-stabilize a 100-ton rock) is answerable without additional detail, though.

Comment: @ErinAnne - thank you for your answer. We cannot get definite answers when asteroid mining is a concern. But these questions will have to be studied and answered. Let's say, we are not pushing rock from an asteroid quarry. Let's say this is Earth and you have tools and machinery to chisel this rock. What kind of precision would you need?

Comment: Or closer to Earth example. You have spacecraft in orbit with two engines. One engine malfunctioned. Now, when you do an orbit transfer, you have only one engine firing which creates off-balance. Can you adjust the nozzle of this engine to compensate and have precise orbit transfer?

Comment: I saw this in the HNQ list and guessed that it was an uhoh question.

Comment: What exactly does the OP mean by "fixed axis"?  Does this mean capturing a very irregular mass in a structure  having two pivots? Getting the pivots suitably aligned with center of mass so that spin induced wobble is minimized could be an interesting engineering challenge. Also... now propulsion and guidance need to cope the spinning mass's  gyroscopic precession.   A non-spinning mass seems easier to drive around.

Comment: @BradV - Interesting point "A non-spinning mass seems easier to drive". There is no railroad. If you push something in space, how would you control the direction (so that object does not go sideways)? As "SE - stop firing the good guys" noted, spinning and determining "couple of axis" is one way to manage it.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance  pushing means you need to push perfectly thru C.M. regardless if spinning or not.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance if you are going to push something that is spinning... you need to have it in a fixture/structure of some sort or else bring object to total zero spin and then push it along, let it go ballistic and THEN spin it up. But why bother spinning it if does not buy you much practical benefit?

Comment: @BradV- that is precisely the question. Can you navigate something without rotating gyroscopes (or rotating rock)? How would you define and adjust to a virtual axis? On the other hand, if you create a "gyroscope" from an irregular piece of rock, your engineering task apparently will get easier.

Comment: Instead of pushing it, try pulling it.  That should take care of a lot of your problems right off the top.

Comment: @Roger - Sorry, I don't see it. When you pull something without a rigid connection, you have much less control about what dangles behind. Plus, it will get in the way of firing engines.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance What I mean is: attach a rope to any random point on any random object and give it a yank, and the center of gravity lines up with the center of effort all by itself.

Comment: @Roger - There will be inevitable side motions of the object on a rope. Any attempt to adjust the course by space tug - will only increase these side motions. But your suggestion would work - in the water, not in a vacuum.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two observations:

1. Any reasonable way of nudging a NEO towards Earth requires doing a burn months or even years in advance. Compared to the burn time (here 1min), that means we have a lot of time to do adjustments before and after the main burn.
2. A 100-ton rock does not have a very large moment of inertia. Rotating it around is no big deal.

So what's required of the space tug is just to have an attitude control system with small RCS thrusters, which it is going to need anyway if it's going to do precision docking with a rock. Additionally, two axis engine gimbaling would be nice.

The procedure would then be approximately like this:

1. Dock with the rock.
2. Do tiny RCS burns to give the asteroid a little angular velocity. With a couple of axis this should be enough to figure out exactly where the centre of mass is located.
3. Orient the asteroid in the same way.
4. Gimbal the engine to align with the centre of mass. This can also be done with the claws/feet/anchors attached.
5. Do the main burn.
6. Remain attached for a couple of hours, confirming the new velocity.
7. Do tiny corrections with the RCS thrusters
8. Detach.

Comment: "SE - stop firing the good guys" - thank you very much for your answer. This is what I wanted to confirm. Although, it is still a mystery to me how they've been successfully performing these course correction maneuvers since 60-th, especially gravitational assist maneuvers.  From an ignorant point of view, it would require micron level precision.

Comment: "A 100-ton rock does not have a very large moment of inertia. Rotating it around is no big deal.": for comparison, the ISS is about 420 metric tons. It was accidentally flipped around 540 degrees by an unintended thruster firing on the Nauka module.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance Why "micron level precision"? Space is _really big_, getting something wrong by a few kilometres rarely matters.

Comment: @TooTea - "Precision" tolerances. This is what I am trying to understand. For example, if you push a 100-ton piece of NEO asteroid Bennu - and you want to change trajectory in such a way, that this 100-ton piece - hit the Earth's atmosphere for  “Aerocapture” orbital transfer maneuver. What would be my room for error (precision) in terms of fraction of degree of an angle (for applied acceleration force)?

Comment: Iteration is key. You make a trajectory change maneuver, monitor the result, and if necessary, make another one. Repeat as needed until arrival at destination. The earlier you make the corrections and the more accurate your adjustment and monitoring, the more efficient you'll be, but with a little extra propellant you can get by with sloppier maneuvers.